# How can we open `seller_ids` view on `purchase.order.line`

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

If product price is more than vendor list than can we open `seller_ids` view on `purchase.order.line` ?

Comment: Can you describe more ?

Comment: In `purchase.order` we entered product on `purchase.order.line` and that time i need if product price is less available in `seller_ids` that time i want to open one view for display `seller_ids` list.